# Как импортировать свою библиотеку Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Создал себе небольшую библиотеку, теперь хочу импортировать ее в проект. Как?

Comment: А что нагуглить уже удалось. Какие способы попробовали уже?

Answer (score 0):

Я понял, нужно скомпилировать проект, подключить ссылку на bin/Debug/[libname], а затем подключить с помощью using